# Can't access one-to-many relationships in CoreData using Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

Swift has gotten me to finally give IOS development a try, but I'm having some issues with CoreData. I'm having no luck trying to access my properties that map to my one-to-many relationships.

I've got a one-to-many relationship set up as such:

```
@objc(Project)
class Project: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name:String

    @NSManaged var scribbles : Array<Scribble>

}

@objc(Scribble)
class Scribble: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var notes:String

    @NSManaged var project:Project

}
```

I fetch my data like this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Projects");
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
request.includesSubentities = true;

var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil);
for project in results
{
     let thisProject:Project = project as Project;
     projects.append(thisProject);
}
```

But whenever I try to iterate over the scribbles for a project using for..in  I get this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Scribble count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

When I println on my project object It looks like I'm getting something back, I just don't know what to do with it.

```
<Project: 0xb48e010> (entity: Projects; id: 0xb48d340 <x-coredata://CDEFAC19-4D9E-426D-B0CC-EFFEE9053707/Projects/p3> ; data: {
name = Larry;
scribbles = "0xb48e7b0 <x-coredata://CDEFAC19-4D9E-426D-B0CC-EFFEE9053707/Scribbles/p3>";
```

})

Comment: Not sure if this is whats causing your exception, but you can't store an Array in core data - only an NSSet or an NSOrderedSet.

Comment: @alivingston I tried changing it to an NSSet, but that didn't make it work.  I got reason: '-[Scribble countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb490220' instead.

Comment: Can you post the code for the for in thats causing the exception?

Comment: Pretty much just "for scribble in project[index].scribbles{...}"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the exception that's being thrown, it appears you're trying to iterate over a collection, but instead project.scribbles returning a collection, its returning an instance of Scribble.

That makes me think that your relationship is set up as 'to one' in the data modeler.  Make sure that you've set the relationship to 'to many'.  You can do that by selecting the relationship, and there will be an option in the Data Model Inspector called type - it's set to 'to one' by default.